# ASP.NET Core Web API Deployed project fails with 503 http error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I tried to upload an asp.net core web api (for .NET core 2.1) test project on windows 12r2 (under IIS) and for some reason I get 503 http error.
The installation procedure seems to be correct: the app pool is set to "no managed code"
The Site points to the folder containing the published code.
I also installed dotnet-hosting-2.1.19-win.exe and .NET Core runtime on Windows 12R2.
Any ideas?

I checked youtube, they do the same but it works on their side. The only doubt I have is whether Windows 12R2 is ok for this

Answer (score 0):

What is the full error message that you see? Is it 502 Process failure? If yes, you may refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/, I followed it and it working flawlessly.

Comment: 503 Service unavailable

Comment: Moreover, the simple html temporary 1 page site working in another pool stopped working once I installed dotnet-hosting-2.1.19-win

Comment: @JoeDoe 503 service unavailable means your application pool stop working. Please check it on your IIS.

Comment: The iis pool stops working after I try to call the service. I updated windows and now I get 500.19 instead of 503. It does not like config, however the config I have is a default config you get when you create a new Web API using .NET Core. It has only the Values controller and no code from my side. It works fine on IISExpress locally but it does not work when I deploy it. I tried all the options and I don't know how to run the asp.net core web api.

Comment: Have you checked full error message on the server? 500 internal error is generic issue, you may need to check the error message on the server. If there is no issue with your application, your application pool won't stop on IIS.